# How would I clear a player of a certain head in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I clear a player of a certain head in Minecraft?

I tried using

```
/clear Diamondman211 skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:Bacon}
```

(The `SkullOwner` name doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

For `/clear`, it's `/clear <player> <item> <damage> <count>` rather than count before damage, as is the case with for example `/give`, so it should be `/clear Diamondman211 skull 3 1 {SkullOwner:Bacon}`